# How to create a Sugar ORM database when app first installed?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sugarorm

I am developing an android app which needs a database. That database contains about 80 states and their cities (approximately 900 entries).

There are two spinners in the activity. Users choose state from first spinner (e.g. California, New York, Texas), and chooses one city of that state (e.g. Los Angeles, San Francisco, San Diego) from second spinner.

How can I create that Sugar ORM database when app first installed?

Comment: Sugar ORM is ORM and not database. Database is sqlite. Anyway, you don't need to create anything, only you need is to feel db with data.

Comment: Should I add all of 900 entries manually?

Comment: How do you have that 900 entries? If you have a file just parse file and add to db.

Comment: I have a file and I get entries from that file. What I understand that : I create an SQLite database and add entries from the file. Then i reach that database over Sugar ORM. Right?

Comment: Try to understand what ORM is and then everything will be easy.

Comment: @cimenmus Yes. Make sure to use `.saveInTx()` if possible, to massively speed up the data import process.

Comment: Read http://satyan.github.io/sugar/